# set an element at center position css

Tags: css

In css styling **margin:0px auto;** is centers the element in x-axis.

But I want center the same in y-axis.

```
     ^
     |
     |
<----E---->
     |
     |
     v
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: try `margin-right: auto; margin-left: auto; margin-top: auto; margin-bottom: auto; `

Comment: No use. it placed at top

Comment: Can you add a link to a snippet, or at least some example HTML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div id = "centerDiv"></div>
```

CSS

```
#centerDiv
{
  width: 200px;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

This code helps to center horizontally.

EDITED:

Try this [link](http://jsfiddle.net/mcSfe/). I think this is what you want :-)

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you need *drumroll* FLEXBOX!!! Set the following styles on your parent element while you keep the child element with an explicitly defined width and `margin: 0 auto;`

```
.parent {
    display: box;
    box-orient: horizontal;
    box-pack: center;
    box-align: center;
}
```

check it out: http://jsfiddle.net/6j5Ah/

Hope you're using a sweet new browser cause this is NOT going to work in your grandpa's browser (http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox).

Read more than I could ever hope to know at HTML5rocks.com: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/flexbox/quick/#toc-center

Also keep in mind that the spec has changed a bit around flexbox and there's a new syntax for it. The one I've posted is the old (2009) syntax since it has wider support. That will be changing as browsers move into the future. You can find more information about the differences on CSS Tricks-- http://css-tricks.com/old-flexbox-and-new-flexbox/

Comment: Not the cross browser though, but deserves +1

Answer (score 0):

if you know the box's size, you can use the position, like this:

#### HTML

```
<div class="center"></div>
```

#### CSS

```
.center {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-top: height /2;
  margin-left: width / 2;
  width: ... px;
  height: ...px;
}
```

Another method,please click [here](http://www.w3cplus.com/css/vertically-center-content-with-css).